# Get the TypeScript type of a variable

Tags: typescript

Is there an expression that evaluates to the type that TypeScript believes a values inhabits?

---

I've been trying to search, but all the answers are about Javascript's runtime types and not TypeScript's types.

For example

```ts
const a = 5 as unknown as string;
console.log(typeof a);
// number
```

The above print "number" because it's getting a type from JavaScript at runtime. Typescript, however, assumes that a is a String. The following type checks because TypeScript believes a is a String:

```ts
function naiveType(v: string): string {
  return "string";
}

const a = 5 as unknown as string;
console.log(naiveType(a));
```

Comment: No, because a) Typescript types don't exist at runtime so there's literally nothing to print and b) there is no "the type" because a value could have any number of types depending on context.

Comment: @GuyIncognito a) I'm not asking about resolving a runtime type, I get that by then it's been compiled to JavaScript. I want to know about the type it has during the type checking phase of compilation B) Yes there is,TypeScript keeps track of structural type information as it's type checking, how else can it perform inference or type check anything.

Comment: No there isn't. For example you can have `type Foo = 5` and then the type of `a = 5` could be either a Number or Foo or something else, depending on context. And anything that prints the compile-time type inference can't really give you any information that you don't already have; you could theoretically print the type(s) of compile-time constants but you can't have a function that prints types at runtime because again, types don't exist at runtime and when the function would run the compile phase has already long since passed.

Comment: Emitting any TS type information to JavaScript is one of TypeScript's stated [Non-Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals), so there's nothing you can `console.log()`.  All TS type system information is gone by then.  If you want that information you need to use IntelliSense or something instead; does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @GuyIncognito That's clearly wrong. Whatever type typescript gives `a` should unify with Foo (sure), but that's immaterial. TypeScript is generating all sorts of JavaScript already, resolving an expression to a string it well within its capabilities. Whether it does so is the question, static-types not existing at runtime really shouldn't be contentions. That's fine.

Comment: It doesn't do so is the answer.

Comment: @jcalz I read that to mean there's no intention to include runtime reflection for static type, but it seems I'm mistaken and people are apparently shaken up about it. Good to know, I suppose!

Comment: So would you like to see an answer written up here that says "this is not possible" along with sources (such as the non-goals document, or the [TS Feature Request template](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7addca63aed56153397d41ad93db272a2ded0f54/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/Feature_request.md) that wants to be sure that the feature "could be implemented without emitting different JS based on the types of the expressions")?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse this is not possible with the TypeScript compiler.

---

One of TypeScript's [Design Non-Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) is that TypeScript would:

> 5. Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system.  Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata.

If there were a `tsTypeof` operator that acted the way you want, the TypeScript code

```
// TS
const a = 5 as unknown as string;
console.log(tsTypeof a);
```

would need to compile to something like the following JavaScript

```
// JS
const a = 5;
console.log("string");
```

while the TypeScript code

```
// TS
const a = 5 as unknown as number;
console.log(tsTypeof a);
```

would need to compile to something like

```
// JS
const a = 5;
console.log("number");
```

which means that `tsTypeof a` would compile to different things depending on the results of the type system, which violates the rule.

---

If someone were to open a feature request for such an operator, it would almost certainly be declined, since one couldn't truthfully check the box in [the TypseScript feature request issue template](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7addca63aed56153397d41ad93db272a2ded0f54/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/Feature_request.md) that says

> ☑ This could be implemented without emitting different JS based on the types of the expressions.

---

If you want something like this, you'd need to add a build step that used, say, [the TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) to process your TypeScript code and convert it to a form that preserves the compile-time type information.  There are certainly existing frameworks that do this for you, such as [Deepkit's `typeOf()` function](https://docs.deepkit.io/english/runtime-types.html#runtime-types-reflection).  But this takes us outside the realm of pure TypeScript and into external tools, which isn't the focus of this question.